# SWR with graphql-request how to add variables in swr?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, swr

I want to add variables to my swr which fetch using graphql request. this is my code

```
import { request } from "graphql-request";
import useSWR from "swr";

const fetcher = (query, variables) => request(`https://graphql-pokemon.now.sh`, query, variables);

export default function Example() {
  const variables = { code: 14 };
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    `query GET_DATA($code: String!) {
                getRegionsByCode(code: $code) {
                  code
                  name
                }
              }`,
    fetcher
  );

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;
}
```

but I dont know how to add `variables` into swr fetcher as I know `useSWR(String, fetcher)` string is for query, and fetcher for fetch function, where I can put the variables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Multiple Arguments](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#multiple-arguments), you can use an array as the `key` parameter for the `useSWR` react hook.

```
import React from "react";
import { request } from "graphql-request";
import useSWR from "swr";

const fetcher = (query, variables) => {
  console.log(query, variables);
  return request(`https://graphql-pokemon.now.sh`, query, variables);
};
export default function Example() {
  const variables = { code: 14 };
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    [
      `query GET_DATA($code: String!) {
          getRegionsByCode(code: $code) {
            code
            name
          }
        }`,
      variables,
    ],
    fetcher
  );

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;
}
```

The function `fetcher` still accepts the same 2 arguments: `query` and `variables`.

Comment: This is discouraged by the [SWR documentation here](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments) and will result in unnecessary rerenders.

Answer (score 12):

SWR author here!

Agreed that this is a critical feature to have, that's why since v1.1.0, **SWR keys will be serialized automatically and stably**. So you can safely do this:

```js
useSWR(['query ...', variables], fetcher)
```

While `variables` can be a JavaScript object (can be nested, or an array, too), and it will not cause any unnecessary re-renders. Also, the serialization process is stable so the following keys are identical, no extra requests:

```js
// Totally OK to do so, same resource!
useSWR(['query ...', { name: 'foo', id: 'bar' }], fetcher)
useSWR(['query ...', { id: 'bar', name: 'foo' }], fetcher)
```

You can directly pass an object as the key too, it will get passed to the fetcher:

```js
useSWR(
  {
    query: 'query ...',
    variables: { name: 'foo', id: 'bar' }
  },
  fetcher
)
```

You can try it out by installing the latest version of SWR, let me know if there's any issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution from [slideshowp2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65562706/1070117) did not help me since it resulted in an infinite loop.

Don't pass an object to the `useSWR` function since they change on every re-render. Pass the variables directly:

```
const fetcher = (query, variables) => {
  console.log(query, variables);
  return request(`https://graphql-pokemon.now.sh`, query, variables);
};
export default function Example() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    [
      `query GET_DATA($code: String!) {
          getRegionsByCode(code: $code) {
            code
            name
          }
        }`,
      14,
    ],
    (query, coder => fetcher(query, { code })
  );

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while trying to implement the "best answer" solution here on this post and it simply wasn't working. After a lot of debugging and following the guide provided from [swr's docs](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments), I finally got the following solution to work:

(note i decided to use a tuple but you can do whatever)

```js
 import useSWR from "swr";
 import { request } from "graphql-request";

 
 // fetcher
 const fetcher = (url: string, token: any) => {
    return request(url, token[0], token[1]);
  };

  // shape of request
  const token = [
    `query Lesson($lessonId: ID!) {
      lesson(id: $lessonId) {
        _id
        title
        description
        bookmarked
      }
    }`,
    variables,
  ];

  // swr hook
  const { data } = useSWR(["http://localhost:4000/", token], ([url, token]) =>
    fetcher(url, token)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.0.0 you have to use the following fetcher:

```
const fetcher = ([query, variables]) => graphQLClient.request(query, variables);

const { data } = useSWR([query, variables], fetcher)
```

Doc: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#multiple-arguments