# useSWR with graphql-request keeps sending requests infinitely after arguments are passed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, next.js, swr

Here I am creating a custom hook for getting list of bookings with arguments, `search`, which is the `status` of the booking and is by default 'NEW' and it can be reused anywhere with different `search` value and get the status bookings.

The problem is that request is successful and its getting the result according to the argument passed.

**But on Network calls it keeps sending the request infinitely to the server, like 4 requests/sec**

Custom Hook for getting Bookings

```
import { getBookingList } from "@graphql/bookings/queries";
import { swrFetcher } from "../fetcher";
import useSWR from "swr";

function useBooking(search="NEW") {
    const { data, error } = useSWR([getBookingList, {search}], swrFetcher);
    return { data: data && data?.bookingList, error };
}

export default useBooking;
```

This is the graphql query that is taking the arguments and being executed.

GraphqQL Query for getting booking list with input arguments.

```
import { gql } from "graphql-request";

export const getBookingList = gql`
    query getBookingList($search: String) {
        bookingList(search: $search) {
            id
            date
            pickupLoc {
                coordinates
            }
            dropoffLoc {
                coordinates
            }
            time
            pickup
            dropoff
            journey
            price
            name
            status
            driver {
                id
                referenceId
                user {
                    username
                }
            }
            driverNotes
            customerNotes
            customer {
                phone
            }
            paymentType
            vehicleType {
                name
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

This is my swrFetcher which is used to fetch the data from graphql with SWR.

```
import { GraphQLClient } from "graphql-request";

const graphqlFetcher = new GraphQLClient(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_API}`);

export const swrFetcher = (query, variables) => graphqlFetcher.request(query, variables);
```

I followed this [Arguments in SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments) and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480752/swr-with-graphql-request-how-to-add-variables-in-swr), but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake, i was doing it wrong.
After looking onto the [Multiple Arguments](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#multiple-arguments) section of the here it was clearly mentioned about this issue.
Just needed to change my custom hook to this:

```
const { data, error } = useSWR([getBookingList, search], (url, value) => swrFetcher(url, { search: value }));
```

and everything worked after that.